# spring mvc deploy cloud foundry error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry

I wroted an SpringMVC app and run it in Tomcat correctly, but when I deploy it onto an Cloud Foundry compatible PaaS, it outputs the following errors,

45:37.07+0800 [App/0]   OUT INFO: validateJarFile(/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/javaee-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
45:40.23+0800 [App/0]   OUT 2014-10-20 11:45:40,238
**45:40.23+0800 [App/0]   OUT INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath**
45:40.39+0800 [App/0]   OUT 2014-10-20 11:45:40,395
**45:40.39+0800 [App/0]   OUT INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext**
45:42.65+0800 [App/0]   OUT [CONTAINER] guration.spring.CloudApplicationContextInitializer INFO    Initializing Spring Environment for Cloud Foundry
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT [CONTAINER] guration.spring.CloudApplicationContextInitializer SEVERE  Unexpected exception on initialization: null
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT java.lang.NullPointerException
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT       at auto_reconfig.org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.RedisServiceInfoCreator.createServiceInfo(RedisServiceInfoCreator.java:26)
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT       at auto_reconfig.org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.RedisServiceInfoCreator.createServiceInfo(RedisServiceInfoCreator.java:12)
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT       at auto_reconfig.org.springframework.cloud.AbstractCloudConnector.getServiceInfo(AbstractCloudConnector.java:61)
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT       at auto_reconfig.org.springframework.cloud.AbstractCloudConnector.getServiceInfos(AbstractCloudConnector.java:40)
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT       at auto_reconfig.org.springframework.cloud.Cloud.getServiceInfos(Cloud.java:89)
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT       at auto_reconfig.org.springframework.cloud.Cloud.getCloudProperties(Cloud.java:201)
45:43.03+0800 [App/0]   OUT       at

Comment: Are you uploading a war file?  It looks like to be a classpath issue...

Comment: Going to need more info.  Include the command and full output of `cf push`.  Also, include any information about services that you've bound to the app.  The output of `cf services` should be a good start.  Just make sure you *remove any sensitive info* like passwords from anything service related that you post.